# IMAP command to show headers + size of message

Tags: syntax, imap

I am looking for the syntax to show both message headers (to, from, subject, date), as well as message size when issuing an IMAP command via OpenSSL or telnet.

Currently, I am using:

```
. fetch 1:* (body[header.fields (from to subject date)])
```

and

```
. fetch 1:* (rfc822.size)
```

I am using these as separate commands, but I was wondering if there is a way to integrate them into a single command.  I haven't been able to figure it out myself and wonder if anybody here knows of a way.

Comment: Yep, just put both in the same parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put both data items in the list:

```
. fetch 1:* (rfc822.size body[header.fields (from to subject date)])
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I feel dumb for not trying that.  Thanks a bunch!